# Typecasting error in C

Tags: c

```
873: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'fabl_infod_twamp_reply_t*'
```

And the code in lines 870-873 is;

```
     870:        reply_hdr = 
     871:              fabl_infod_extract_from_message(sizeof(fabl_infod_twamp_reply_t), 
     872:                                   &buffer_pos,
     873:                                   &buffer_length);
```

The function parameters for "fabl_infod_extract_from_message";

```
static inline void * fabl_infod_extract_from_message (uint32_t struct_size, 
                                  uint8_t **buffer_pos, 
                                  uint32_t *buffer_length)
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Though I have tried typecating as;

```
reply_hdr =  (void *)fabl_infod_extract_from_message(sizeof(fabl_infod_twamp_reply_t), 
                                        &buffer_pos,
                                        &buffer_length);
```

Comment: In C all conversions from `void*` to pointer to any object are always valid. C tag removed and title edited.

Comment: You just cast from void* to void*... what's the point

Comment: @Shane: Could you print the value of `__cplusplus__` from within your file somewhere? It's fairly likely that you are accidentally compiling with a c++ compiler instead of a c compiler.

Comment: @Shane: Additionally, what is the name of the file that is producing these errors? In particular, I'm interested in the file extension.

Comment: Cast to `fabl_infod_twamp_reply_t*` instead of to `void*`

Comment: @Bill: It's *.c, and its taken care of now. Thank you though.

Comment: This was ***not*** a C++ question. It could be, though, if the OP was actually using C++. What _compiler_ they were using was probably the root of it. Sorry about that, @Shane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting a `void*` to a `void*` has very little effect.

If the actual return value from `fabl_infod_extract_from_message` (i.e. "behind" the `void*`) is a `fabl_infod_twamp_reply_t*`, you should cast it to that type:

```
reply_hdr = (fabl_infod_twamp_reply_t*) fabl_infod_extract_from_message ...
```

or, using a C++-style cast:

```
reply_hdr = static_cast<fabl_infod_twamp_reply_t*>(fabl_infod_extract_from_message...
```